# R: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label

Tags: r

I'm getting error in making a plot with geom_point.

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

mtcars$`car name` <- rownames(mtcars) 
mtcars$mpg_z <- round((mtcars$mpg - mean(mtcars$mpg))/sd(mtcars$mpg), 2)  
mtcars$mpg_type <- ifelse(mtcars$mpg_z < 0, "below", "above") 
mtcars <- mtcars[order(mtcars$mpg_z), ]  # sort
mtcars$`car name` <- factor(mtcars$`car name`, levels = mtcars$`car name`) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(x=`car name`, y=mpg_z,label=mpg_z), stat='identity', fill="black", size=6)  +
  geom_text(color="white", size=2) +
  labs(title="Diverging Lollipop Chart", 
       subtitle="Normalized mileage from 'mtcars': Lollipop") + 
  ylim(-2.5, 2.5) +
  coord_flip()
```

But I was not able to put numbers inside of the points and having the error:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
```

The plot is here. Thank you in advance!!!
[image]

Comment: `label` is an aesthetic for `geom_text` not `geom_point`.

Comment: @dorayin If you have found the solution to your problem, please accept one of the answers (stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that this thread won't be active anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a different way to do it that I personally find to be more appealing (it also avoids the issue of overlapping labels for points in close vicinity):

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.4.3
library(ggrepel)
#> Warning: package 'ggrepel' was built under R version 3.4.2
theme_set(theme_bw())

mtcars$`car name` <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$mpg_z <-
  round((mtcars$mpg - mean(mtcars$mpg)) / sd(mtcars$mpg), 2)
mtcars$mpg_type <- ifelse(mtcars$mpg_z < 0, "below", "above")
mtcars <- mtcars[order(mtcars$mpg_z),]  # sort
mtcars$`car name` <-
  factor(mtcars$`car name`, levels = mtcars$`car name`)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = mtcars,
    mapping = aes(x = `car name`, y = mpg_z),
    stat = 'identity',
    fill = "black",
    size = 6
  )  +
  geom_text(color = "white", size = 2) +
  labs(title = "Diverging Lollipop Chart",
       subtitle = "Normalized mileage from 'mtcars': Lollipop") +
  ylim(-2.5, 2.5) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = mtcars,
                            mapping = aes(x = `car name`, y = mpg_z, label = mpg_z))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-13 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to put numbers inside the points?

Answer (score 3):

Just move your `aes` call into `ggplot`

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=`car name`, y=mpg_z,label=mpg_z)) + 
  geom_point(stat='identity', fill="black", size=6)  +
  geom_text(color="white", size=2) +
  labs(title="Diverging Lollipop Chart", 
       subtitle="Normalized mileage from 'mtcars': Lollipop") + 
  ylim(-2.5, 2.5) +
  coord_flip()
```

`geom_point` and `geom_text` will then inherit the relevant aesthetics.

Comment: Thank you! I knew this way but I'd like to use different datasets for geom_bars and other functions (which I didn't include here). So I need to keep the ggplot() empty.

Comment: You can move the data to the relevant geom and leave the aes in ggplot, or you can move the aes as well, but label has no place in geom_point